# Как поместить данный код в цикл?

Tags: javascript, циклы

```
if(data.boolean1 == "true"){
  document.getElementById("checkbox1").checked = true;
}
```

Через цикл будет убоднее, там еще 6 таких.
Пробовал сделать, не получалось на этапе конкатенации. Нужно было boolean+i сделать, выдавало NaN

Answer (score 0):

Ответ на текущий вопрос такой:

```
data['boolean' + i] == "true"
```

Но правильнее работать с классами и массивами данных, а не присваиваеть каждому элементу номер